# IIS trimming %20 from end of url

Tags: iis

I have a problem where a url encoded space at the end of a url doesn't get passed to the PHP script. When using Apache the %20 makes it to the Php script. Is there a way to have iis not trim it?

Comment: Can you give an example of the URL?

Comment: http://domain.com/index.php/deletetax/9.000%25%20

Comment: @ChrisMuench that URL has no data (at least not now). Do you have another? Or better yet - can you post code here?

Comment: The url is just an example. The real url is an Ajax call behind a login.

Comment: I'm not an expert in IIS but that sounds like a Rewrite Rule issue. In that case, try [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com/questions/324384/iis-rewrite-rewrite-maps-and-query-strings)

Comment: Adding a `/` at the end of the URL should fix your problem.

Comment: It seems that you are fairly certain that this is a IIS vs Apache issue (and most likely it is). However, as a matter of protocol, I would suggest challenging that assumption. Check your PHP.ini in both installations, or better yet, throw a `phpinfo()` page to ensure that the configuration is, in fact, identical in both.

Comment: They are the same (phpinfo()). I have also tried on multiple IIS servers.

Answer (score -1):

If i understand your question, this might help:
Create a file named *.htaccess* in the main directory of your website and add this to it:

```
# remove spaces from start or after /
RewriteRule ^(.*/|)[\s%20]+(.+)$ $1$2 [L]

# remove spaces from end or before /
RewriteRule ^(.+?)[\s%20]+(/.*|)$ $1$2 [L]

# replace spaces by - in between
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]*)(?:\s|%20)+(.*)$ $1-$2 [L,R]
```

It will use - instead of %20.
Example: `http://example.com/hello world`
will be

```
http://example.com/hello-world
```

Comment: The OP uses IIS, not Apache.